# Question led to a followup question — asked in separate question, marked duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I asked: [Why does Finder.app Sort by Kind sort extensions in reverse order](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/456835/finder-app-reverse-sort).
The answer was: *Sort by Kind doesn't sort by extension.* Fair enough.
The question answers the unexpected (*to some*) behavior of `Sort by Kind`.

I then asked in a separate question how to perform what I had originally intended:
[Is it possible to sort by extension?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/456839/finder-app-sort-by-extension-not-by-kind)

I provided a link in the former question to the latter,
so anyone expecting `Sort by Kind` to sort by extension and learning it doesn't
will have a path to the answer of how to do it, and
anyone seeking an answer to the more general
*Is it possible to sort by extension?*
might find the answer contained in its own question.

The latter was marked duplicate, but they seem separable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question wasn‘t answered, it got some comments from other users to help you shape your question. The preferable course of action in such cases is to edit the question to give it more focus or make it ask what you wanted to ask.

The new question you asked lacks context (which is present in the first question) and doesn‘t show any research done on your side. So the two „on hold“ reasons which apply are „lack of research“ and „duplicate“. I choose the second, because as mentioned above, editing is better than spreading the same question across two posts.